# _ not recognized when used in a Meteor package

Tags: javascript, meteor, package, underscore.js

I've created a bare-bones Meteor project, with a basic package. In the package, I want to use `_.extend()`. Even after I explicitly use `meteor add underscore`, this fails with the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined
```

Here are my steps:

```
$ meteor create UnderScore
$ cd UnderScore/
$ meteor add underscore
$ meteor create --package unscore
$ meteor add unscore
```

In the file `UnderScore/packages/unscore/unscore.js`, I add the code

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  var object = {}
  _.extend(object, {key: value}) // ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE
}
```

I now use `meteor run` to launch the app, and open the browser at http://localhost:3000

Immediately, I get an error report in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined                unscore.js:3
```

I can access `_` with no problem in the JavaScript files which are not inside a package. What is the correct voodoo to use to make `_` visible inside a package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for your package to use underscore, it needs to be added as a dependency. Your `packages/unscore/package.js` should look something like this:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.use('underscore');
  api.addFiles('unscore.js');
});
```